# How to upload file in angularjs using webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, webmethod, image-upload

:: Asp.net webform ::

One or more images or files upload in angularjs by using asp.net webmethod.
and
insert multi-image into database array format (like:,. [image1, image2, image3]).

For any related information please tell me.
 My Code::

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/error-for-upload-image-in-angularjs-and-webmethod

Comment: @NRepesh share your code of what you have done so far.

Comment: see the link @abhi314